# Como puedo hacer un metodo con 2 argumentos en angular?

Tags: angular

Necesito que un método reciba 2 variables en angular que sera mi palabra a buscar y el numero de pagina para que yo maquete mi url con esas variables osea la palabra a buscar y el numero de pagina

```js
return this.http.get<Articulo[]>(this.url + 'articulos/general?p=' + this.datarecibed + '&page=' + this.paganum);
```

Asi deberia quedar la url pero no se como hacer que reciba los 2 parametros ya que tengo métodos individuales para cada uno y necesito un metodo para los 2 argumentos

Comment: Hola bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, porfavor revisa el [tour] y de paso lee [ask] para poder ayudarte y que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar [ask] que te brinda información acerca de 

como formular preguntas en el sitio, agrega el código como texto por favor, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrías cambiar la concatenación de tu url por string literales para que sea más fácil de modificar y leer

Sobre el método que recibe dos parámetros puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```js
buscar(palabra: string, numero: number): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
  return this.http.get<Articulo[]>(`${this.url}articulos/general?p=${palabra}&page=${numero}`);
}
```